# I need macro for editing Menu in Quick Access Toolbar

Tags: excel, vba

I have questions about [QAT](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win004.htm).

1. How do I add my tooltip to a [button](http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2019/06/18/0002/1030/156678/78/9992366bfc.jpg). How do I add a tooltip to any button?
2. How to change the icon of the [button](http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2019/06/19/0002/1030/156678/78/77c4f7c8ec.jpg) White Arrow?
3. How to insert my own icons?
4. Is it possible to add more [Submenus](http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2019/06/18/0002/1030/156678/78/80f75986f8.jpg). For example Submenus_1; Submenus_2; Submenus_3; Submenus_4; Submenus_5.

Comment: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win001.htm

Comment: @DavidZemens ··· I know, but this won't work for me to edit the menu-button. Olso i find that You can create only 1 menu without any additional submenus. With this string `msoControlPopup`. For picture we can use `.Picture = LoadPicture("C:\Foto\TEST.jpg")
`